# Improving Sagemaker latency

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have created a model using notebook and using java aws sdk when i invoke the endpoint its taking around 7sec. How can i reduce this further and is there any way to have parallel calls.

```
InvokeEndpointRequest request = new InvokeEndpointRequest();
InvokeEndpointResult p = amazonSageMakerRuntime.invokeEndpoint(request.withEndpointName("<endpoint>").withAccept("application/json").withContentType("application/json").withBody(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes())));
```

Comment: 1) what model are we talking about?

2) what's the instance type for the endpoint?

3) what part of the code takes 7s? The invokeEndpoint() API?

4) how are you measuring this? What do you see in Cloudwatch metrics for the endpoint?

5) where is the Java code deployed? On an EC2 instance in the same region? On your local machine?

6) The first call to invokeEndpoint() usually loads the model and is thus slower. What about the next calls?